# Create MS Project report which to return incomplete tasks per user with due date

Tags: ms-project, reporting

I want to be able to produce a report I can share with resources on a project so that they have visibility on what outstanding tasks they have (overdue, current, future) and when they are due.

Ideally this would be grouped by task as multiple resources will assigned to a task, e.g.

Task 1 | Resource 1, Resource 2 | 25/01/2019
Task 2 | Resource 1, Resource 3 | 27/01/2019
Task 3 | Resource 2, Resource 3 | 29/01/2019

I have been looking at the reports functionality and attempted to create a custom report but so far have not been able to create anything that satisfies my requirements.

Is it possible to create a report which satisfies my requirements? If so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Task Usage view shows this information and can be customized just like the Gantt Chart view (add/remove columns, filter data, adjust time-phase zoom, etc.).

[image]

Tip: to add other time-phased fields such as Baseline Work, right click in the Details column and select it from the pop-up menu.